# Wordpress Gutenberg Media Upload Video Gallery

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, upload, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to have exactly the Media Upload Popup that is used when supplying the `gallery` attribute to the `<MediaUpload>` Component. Difference to normal Mediaupload is, that you see a sidebar on the left, and after selecting the items, you reach a view, where you can reorder media like in first image below, not like in the second one that appears with the code I am using:

```
<MediaUpload
  onSelect={ this.onSelectMedia }
  /*todo here should be gallery attr but it will disable video selection*/
  allowedTypes={ [ 'image', 'video' ] }
  accept="image/*,video/*"
  multiple
  value={ this.media.map( ( m ) => m.mediaId ) }
  render={ ( { open } ) => (
    <IconButton
      label={ __( 'Edit Media' ) }
      icon="images-alt2"
      onClick={ open }
    />
  ) }
/>
```

When I add the gallery attribute, the allowedTypes will somehow be overridden by the gallery attribute and only images will be shown in the MediaUpload Window.

### First Image, how it is

[image]

### Second Image, what i need (but with image + video showing)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think this has nothing to do with the `MediaUpload` component itself but with the underlying logic that wordpress only allows attachments of type `image` in its built-in `gallery`. As soon as you add the prop `gallery` to the component the media modal will default to the gallery edit frame. Maybe it’s possible to extend the `gallery` type to also allow other mime-types.

Comment: yes that is what i know and figured already. I would be willing to mimic the exact logic and totaly reimplement the MediaUpload component or anything that would give me that behaviour. But I need code or at least more guiding on how to achive that.